# Issue with custom C++ QuickSort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, g++, quicksort

I am implementing the Quicksort algowithm myself in C++. But I have problems: the result isn't sorted!

Here are my files:
Main file: `quicksort.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#include "quicksort.h"
#include "utils.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    
    print_array(arr);
    cout << endl;

    QuickSort<int, 10>::sort(arr);

    print_array(arr);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`utils.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, size_t N>
void print_array(T (&a)[N]) {
    cout << "{";
    for(auto i: a) { cout << i << ","; }
    cout << "}";
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
void shuffle_array(T (&a)[N]) {
    srand(unsigned(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(&a[0], &a[10], [](int i)-> int {
        unsigned char bytes[i];
        RAND_bytes(bytes, sizeof(bytes));
        return int(bytes[0] % i);
    });
}

#endif /* UTILS_H */
```

`quicksort.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef QUICKSORT_H
#define QUICKSORT_H

#include <iostream>

#include "utils.h"

template<typename T, size_t N>
class QuickSort {
private:
    static bool less(T a, T b) {
        return a < b;
    }

private:
    static void exch(T (&a)[N], int i, int j) {
        T tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }

private:
    static int partition(T (&a)[N], int lo, int hi) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = hi + 1;
        
        while(true) {
            while(less(a[++i], a[lo])) {
                if(i == hi) { break; }
            }

            while(less(a[lo], a[--j])) {
                if(j == lo) { break; }
            }

            if(i >= j) { break; }
            exch(a, i, j);
        }

        exch(a, lo, hi);
        return j;
    }

public:
    static void sort(T (&a)[N]) {
        shuffle_array(a);
        print_array(a);
        cout << endl;
        sort(a, 0, int(N - 1));
    }

private:
    static void sort(T (&a)[N], int lo, int hi) {
        if(hi <= lo) { return; }
        int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
        sort(a, lo, j - 1);
        sort(a, j + 1, hi);
    }
};

#endif /* QUICKSORT_H */
```

Am I missing something? I am compiling this on Linux with:

```sh
$ g++ -pipe -time -o quicksort.exe quicksort.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
```

Please help, I am new in C++.

Comment: Tried debugging jet? What where the insights?

Comment: `exch(a, lo, hi);` seems suspicious?

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, this line exchanges the first and last elements.

Comment: I can see what it does what seems odd is unconditionally exchanging the first and last elements at the end of the partition, why are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the line `exch(a, lo, hi);` should be `exch(a, lo, j);`. It appears to solve your problem:
https://godbolt.org/z/ehh31G

Second - if you're learning c++, use c++ features. That is, use the standard library.
Use `std::array<T, N>` indtead of `T[N]`. Use iterators instead of `int`s for `lo`, `hi`, `i`, `j`. `exch` can be replaced with `std::swap`. `less` can be replaced with `std::less`.

Third - DO NOT use `using namespace std` IN HEADER FILES! Preferably, don't use it at all.

Finally, learn to use your debugger as a comment mentioned.

Good luck.